# Element invertible in integral extension of ring implies invertible in ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Please excuse some minor hiccups in terminology, I am primarily reading this in Swedish so feel free to correct any.

> Let $A\subseteq B$ be an integral extension and $\alpha\in A$ an invertible element in $B$. Show that $\alpha^{-1}\in A$.

This is the question I am currently struggling with. I know that $\alpha\in B$ from the question, which means that there exists a monic polynomial $p\in A[x]$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$. I have also considered that $p(x)=x-z=0$ with $z\in A$ would naturally always imply that $x\in A$, but other monic polynomials can also do that, so I feel it doesn't contribute anything of real substance.

So I am primarily struck on how to approach this to reach the answer; any advice?

Comment: the inverse of $\alpha$ is a root of $\alpha x-1$. But there should also be a monic polynomial...

Comment: That is my thought exactly and where I get stuck kind of, after all we also just need to show that $\alpha^{-1}$ can be a coefficient of a polynomial

Comment: Let $\beta$ be the inverse of $\alpha$ in $B$. There is a monic polynomial $p$ that annihilates $\beta$. What can we say about $p$ versus $\alpha x-1$?

Comment: as it is integral we know $p$ is monoic and $\alpha x-1$ is clearly not, otherwise I am not certain what you're aiming at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find $u_i \in A$ such that $$\alpha^{-n} + u_{n-1} \alpha^{1-n} + \dotsc + u_1 \alpha^{-1} + u_0 = 0.$$
Multiplying with $\alpha^n$ yields
$$1+ (u_{n-1} + \dotsc + u_0 \alpha^{n-1})\alpha = 1 + u_{n-1} \alpha + \dotsc + u_1 \alpha^{n-1} + u_0 \alpha^n = 0.$$
Now you see that $$\alpha^{-1} = -(u_{n-1} + \dotsc + u_0 \alpha^{n-1}) \in A.$$

Comment: but $-(u_{n-1}+...+u_0\alpha^{n-1})$ is not monoic, it has $u_0$ infront of the highest exponent.

Comment: This doesn't play any role. $A$ is a ring, so $u_i \in A, \alpha \in A$ implies $u_{n-1} + \dotsc + u_0 \alpha^{n-1} \in A$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. My bad I got stuck in the thinking of it. You are absolutely correct.